# kubenetes became very slow when it runs too more pods

Tags: performance, kubernetes

I have 3 nodes ,when I create only one app, it start very quickly ，but after a while, it runs 100+ pods, Pending for a long long time,ContainerCreating for a long long time,and “Terminating” is also very very slowly.

Every machine's memory has been used by more than 90%.

Answer (score 0):

Which means that you need to add more nodes. As simple as that.

Comment: Thank you for your intentness.